# How do you restore the last minimized application in Unity from the launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, restore, minimize

I don't know if this is a bug or 'feature' (sadly hoping that it's the former) but when I minimize the last application, I cannot restore it just by clicking its launcher icon. This small screencap shows what's going on : [screencap](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tt9VvwaCWfE)

Do I have to click on the desktop every time I want to restore the last minimized application? Or is it a mis-configuration from my part?

Answer (score 1):

That is a bug, and there are updates for Unity just around the corner. It'll be available in a few days, I think. Hopefully, that'll fix it.

Comment: Is there a launchpad bug or something that I can follow for updates on this issue?

Comment: I don't have a link. Sorry. But the update may have landed, so check for it.

Comment: Update: Still no fix available on Oneiric. Pity as this is the single thing that keeps annoying me crazy in Unity.